# Identity, Credential, & Access Managemen

Tags: security, credentials

I am working as Ops. for a startup team, merging to a big company. The team have some identities, credential and accesses to third-parity services, such as Apple Store, Google Play, etc. set up by former as well as current team member individually. As the person are moving around, the team's business security and operation are impacted. I am looking for better practice to have these under control as well as the possibility to integrate them into parent company's AD/LDAP server.

Could you please share your experience, thought and suggestion?

Thanks
Tiger

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this does not appear to be a programming question.  Additionally, this seems too broad for [SF]; voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your environment, but heck out Keycloak

http://keycloak.jboss.org/

From the features:

- Optional LDAP/Active Directory integration
- CORS Support
- Admin Console for managing users, roles, role mappings, applications,
  user sessions, allowed CORS web origins, and OAuth client
- Supports JBoss AS7, EAP 6.x, Wildfly, Tomcat, Jetty, and Pure Javascript applications.   Plans to support Node.js, RAILS, GRAILS, and other non-Java applications.